# I'm having problem of finding out what is this code order (big-o)?

Tags: big-o

Big-o and efficiency of algorithm!

```
int exp(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return 1;
    if (b == 1) return a;
    int k = exp(a, b / 2);
    k *= k;
    if (b & 1) return k * a;
    return k;
}
```

would someone tell me what Order it is?

Comment: Please post code as text, not links.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring